# Single Page Application in React without React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm trying to build my first single page application using React. I would like to build the web application without using any external libraries, such as React-Router. Also, I don't know if this is important to note, but I'm using React over a CDN.

I'm having a hard time finding how to hide and show components on different levels in React. Here is the overall structure of the application:

**dashboard.html**

```
...

<div id="content"> </div>

...
```

**dashboard.js**

```
document.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#content"))
);


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AccountView />
      <PersonsView />
    </div>
  );
}

function AccountView() {
  return (
    <div>
      Foo
    </div>
  );
}

function PersonsView() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Persons />
      <AddPersonForm />
      <button id="showAccountView">Show Account View</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function Persons() {
  return (
    <div>
      Foo
    <button id="showAddPersonForm">Show Add Person Form</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function AddPersonsForm() {
  return (
    <form>
      Bar
    </form>
  );
}
```

In `<App />` I would like to only show the `<PersonsView />`, only when clicking the button (`#showAccountView`), the `<PersonsView />` should be hidden and the `<AccountView />` shown.

Then in `<PersonsView />`, I would like to only show the `<Persons />`, only when clicking the button (`#showAddPersonForm`), the `<Persons />` should be hidden and the `<AddPersonForm />` shown.

Comment: I'd create a global variable where I'd store the current page name, and then, from that, do if elses to show different components related to the current page

Comment: You'd use state values to track the state of your application.  Which elements are shown/hidden/etc. is part of the state of the application.

Answer (score 0):

having a state in your App() can handle the visibility of components. Here is an exemplaric untested implementation:

```
function App() {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('AccountView');
    return (
        <div>
            {location === 'AccountView' && <AccountView />}
            {location === 'PersonsView' && <PersonsView />}
            <Button
                onPress={() => {
                    setLocation(
                        location === 'AccountView'
                            ? 'PersonsView'
                            : 'AccountView',
                    );
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

you can use props to pass the setLocation function to the views or create a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for your app

example how to pass props:

```
// call the account view like this
<AccountView setLocation={setLocation} />;

// and modify the account view like this
function AccountView({ setLocation }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onPress={() => setLocation('yourDestination')}>
                YourButtonText
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: My issue is that button to toggle between views is in the component itself and not in <App />. For example in <PersonView /> is a button ("#showAccountView") to hide <PersonView /> and show <AccountView />.

Comment: as i said. use props or a context to pass setLocation to the view. i edited my answer to include a example how that would be done